# MouseEvent lost in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

This is the code I am using to show the issue which I am facing in another project.

I am not getting any line like this if I use JScrollPane as a wrapper for panel2. **Why?**
I want to click on JscrollPane and got event printed as following.

```
java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_CLICKED,(800,469),absolute(808,499),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,934x612,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.LineBorder@cc0e01,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=880,height=630]]
```

If now I change

```
panel1.add(pane);
```

to

```
panel1.add(panel2);
```

Then the message above got printed.

```
public class LostMouseEvent {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new LostMouseEvent();
}

public LostMouseEvent() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
            JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
            JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel2);

            panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(880, 630));
            panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
            panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(840, 610));
            panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green));


            panel1.add(pane);
            frame.add(panel1);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(950, 650);

            panel1.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
        }
    });
}

private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent me) {
        System.out.println(me);
    }
}
}
```

**UPD:** In fact in my project there is more than just one panel2. Originally, I had panel1 and many panel2 inside. Then I wanted to wrap each panel2 with JScrollPane and started to face this problem.

I need to have only one MouseListener to minimize changes to the code.

Comment: if you click outside the green border it works like it should, what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I want to click inside the green border and got the event printed. Why event from JScrollPane does not bubble up to JPanel panel1?

Comment: you not added MouseListener to the second JPanel, for relative coordinated to use SwingUtilities#convert.... (most efficient from MouseMotionListener)

Comment: @mKorbel I want to add only one MouseListener to panel1 and process all events using it. Is this possible?

Comment: what you want to save, one code line or :-), no idea whats your goal, but AWTEventListener doesn't returns relative coordinates betweens parent and child and vice versa, have look at Swing Utilities

Comment: @mKorbel, please see my update. I have already much in MouseListener assuming there is only one the system. So I don't understand why MouseEvent got lost in JScrollPane.

Comment: I'll to send and longer comment as comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Use [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) for creation and manipulation of Swing components
- Dont call `setSize()` rather call `pack()` before setting `JFrame` visible.
- Dont call `setPrefferedSize()` rather override `getPrefferedSize()`

Your code works as expected, it will only print the message if `panel1` is clicked, note `panel1` is behind `JScrollPane`, thus anything outside the green border is `panel1`. To make it work for both the `JScrollpane`/`panel2` and `JPanel`/`panel1` simply add the `MouseListener` to **BOTH** of the required components:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LostMouseEvent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
        new LostMouseEvent();
            }
        });
    }

    public LostMouseEvent() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                JPanel panel1 = new JPanel() {

                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(880, 630);
                    }

                };
                JPanel panel2 = new JPanel() {

                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(840, 610);
                    }
                };
                JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel2);

                panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
                panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green));


                panel1.add(pane);
                frame.add(panel1);

                MouseListener ml=new MyMouseListener();

                //add mouse listener to panel1 and panel2
                panel1.addMouseListener(ml);
                panel2.addMouseListener(ml);

                //alternatively add to pane
                //pane.addMouseListener(ml);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            System.out.println(me);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I personally would not recommend this, however,

To add a single listener to the `JFrame` that will capture all `MouseEvent`s use `Toolkit` class and call [`addAWTEventListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#addAWTEventListener%28java.awt.event.AWTEventListener,%20long%29) like so:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent awte) {//all mouse events will be processed here you will have to check for the mouse events you are interested in
    System.out.println(awte);
    }
}, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);//for Mouse events only
```

**UPDATE 1:**

You could also add the `MouseListener` to your `JFrame`s *glasspane* via `JFrame.getGlassPane().addMouseListener(ml)` dont forget to set the *glasspane* visible after setting `JFrame` visible. This will allow you to only have to add a single `Listener`. See here:

```
...

MouseListener ml = new MyMouseListener();

//add mouse listener to panel1 and panel2
//panel1.addMouseListener(ml);
//panel2.addMouseListener(ml);

//alternatively add to pane
//pane.addMouseListener(ml);

frame.getGlassPane().addMouseListener(ml);

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);

frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);

...
```

**UPADTE 2:**

The main reason for you having the problem of the `MouseEvent` getting lost in `JScrollPane` is because its a bug. See [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1362237).

The work around shown is:

```
public Test()
  {
    setUI(new javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollPaneUI(){
      public void installListeners(JScrollPane scrollPane){}
    });
    JPanel canvas = new JPanel();
    canvas.add( new JLabel("Test") );

    setViewportView( canvas );
    setVisible(true);
  }
```

Comment: not sure if isn't there long timed bug to use JRootPane rootPane = SwingUtilities.getRootPane(frame);        rootPane.setGlassPane(myGlassPane);

Comment: +1 Not sure either.. guess OP can test it out depending, but I do find it irritating to have to call `setVisible` on glasspane after jframe visible.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp, yeah, I would like to keep only one MouseListener since it has much code and I want not to refactor it a lot considering several of them.

Comment: Actually, I don't understand why JScrollPane does consume event without delivering it to panel1. If the event is skipped by pane and delivered to panel1 it would be the best for me.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp, this does not make clearer to me. In the code without JScrollPane there is panel2 inside panel1 and I click on panel2 and event got delivered to panel1.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov its seems to be a bug: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1362237

Comment: @DavidKroukamp, seems to be well-known bug, but not fixed yet for some reasons.

Answer (score 4):

> MouseEvent lost in JScrollPane

- answer is very / quite simple, be sure that there isn't something about lost events, nor with JScrollPane,
- Swing JComponent can firing event only if is there added proper Listener
- you not added MouseListener to second JPanel,
- this JPanel is placed into parent JPanel, this parent has added MouseListener then firing mouseEvent, sure in your case only outside of Bounds of 2nd JPanel added to this container
- then 2nd  JPanel is deepestComponentAt, and not possible fire event without redispatch coordinates from parent to child
- you can to redispatch event programatically too,

Comment: +1 for mentioning `SwingUtilities#deepestComponentAt` and re-dispatching events

Comment: Guys, I still don't understand why without JScrollPane event received, and with JScrollPane it is not. Can you please explain for these both cases?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp, I have tried to dispatchEvent from panel2 to panel1 and it works in simple example. I am going to apply it in the real one.